# Creating new geometries from existing data into routes using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a number of roadlinks in which I have created routes from i.e. for each roadlink I have given a '1' or '0' indicator to whether it was part of a specified route or not with each route its own column and given a unique number. This is outlined in the figure below.
[image]

I now need to change this information in the attribute table into line geometry which visually displays the route as illustrated below. Currently, I am copying features for each route in the attribute table, pasting into a new layer and merging the roadlinks. This process has to be repeated for 1000+ routes. 
[image]

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure how the title matches the question, it should be a short summary.  Do you want to digitise, or do you want to create new geometries from existing digital data?  An example of your data structure and an image of what you want to achieve (or current manual output)  would help to clarify.

Comment: Hi, I’m looking to create new geometries from existing data. Apologies if that was confusing, I’ll amend the title. I don’t have my laptop with me right now but I will add images to help clarify tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing that manually looks like a dreadful job :o I really *need* :) to suggest you to:

- create a database table to keep track of which road segments (or "roadlinks") compose the route
- use a virtual layer to display the routes

To make things simple, I will show you how to use a `sqlite` file, avoiding the need of having a full-fledged database connection.

### Create a SpatiaLite database table

`Layer` -> `Create Layer`->`New SpatiaLite Layer...`

Save it as a file named `road_connections.sqlite`

Define for example the following fields:

1. route_id
2. segment_id
3. seq (the sequential number of the segment within each route)

[image]

### Identify the segments composing the route

For example by visually checking the numbers.
(I am sure that there are some ways to extract these in an automated way, though).

[image]

In this example, the segments are the following:

```
147,173,215,259,276,315,369,389
```

*Please note that in my "roadlinks" layer, the field containing the id is named "segment_id", change yours accordingly.*

### Populate the database

From: `Database` -> `DB Manager...`

Then select `SpatiaLite` -> `road_connections.sqlite` (or how you named your `sqlite` file)

[image]

Run the following query, which adds the segments we previously identified into route #2 (whose name I made up, of course)

```
INSERT INTO road_connections (route_id, segment_id) Values (2,147),(2,173),(2,215),(2,259),(2,276),(2,315),(2,369),(2,389);
```

### Create a virtual layer to display the results

`Layer` -> `Create Layer`->`New Virtual Layer`

[image]

**Edit the layer properties to show each route with its own style:**

[image]

Comment: Hey Raf,

Thanks so much for your detailed reply. I hadn't thought to produce routes as 'pairs' (route and road id). This also eliminates the problem of the columns of table becoming too large because the length is now going to the rows. 

I don't have much experience with sqlite but this is an opportunity to learn. Hope you enjoy the rest of your day.